# Adding a Map inside of an enumeration and putting keys and values in it?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, enumeration

I am still fairly new to java and I was wondering how you would go about putting **Maps** (or **HashMaps**) inside of an **enumeration** while also putting keys and values into the map. Is this even possible? If not, could anyone explain why?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java as EnumMap class that you can you.example shown below.

```
import java.util.EnumMap;

public class Program {

    enum Importance {
    Low, Medium, High, Critical
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create an EnumMap.
    EnumMap<Importance, String> e = new EnumMap<>(Importance.class);
    e.put(Importance.Low, "=Low");
    e.put(Importance.High, "=High");

    // Get values from the map.
    String value1 = e.get(Importance.Low);
    String value2 = e.get(Importance.High);

    System.out.println(value1);
    System.out.println(value2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's just what I needed.

Comment: you are most welcome. i am glad i have been able to help